# How to access a global environment object in a class?

Tags: swiftui, environmentobject

I have a class that needs to update a global environment object. I can pass that environment object between my structs all day, but how do I allow a class object to access the same variable?

```
import SwiftUI

class Global: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var num = 10
}

class MyClass:ObservableObject
{
    @Published var mode = 1
    @EnvironmentObject var global: Global

    func updateMode()
    {
        self.mode += 1
        global.num += 1
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App
{
    let settings = Global()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(settings)
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var global: Global
    @ObservedObject var myClass = MyClass()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Text("Setting \(global.num)")
            Text("Mode \(myClass.mode)")

            Button("Click Me", action: {myClass.updateMode()})
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The following code gives an error:

> Fatal Error: No ObservableObject of type Global found. A
> View.environmentObject(_:) for Global maybe missing an ancestor of
> this view.

I could pass the global object into myClass.updateMode, but then it doesn't seem very global at that point? I would have thought there must be a better way.

Comment: Well, I met the same problem today and raised the exactly same thought.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A possible approach is to make it shared (and don't use `@EnvironmentObject` anywhere **outside SwiftUI view** - it is not designed for that):

```
class Global: ObservableObject
{
    static let shared = Global()

    @Published var num = 10
}

class MyClass:ObservableObject
{
    @Published var mode = 1
    let global = Global.shared    // << here !!

// ...
}

@main
struct MyApp: App
{
    @StateObject var settings = Global.shared  // << same !!
// ...
}
```

Comment: Just a note that you'll need to bind to your @Published values like so: `$settings.num`

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Just convert it to Singleton, EnvironmentObject is designed for Views.